# Should I create module for each web page template?

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular.
I'm starting to build a website using angular 4.4.3.
This website has :

- home page
- list page
- detail page
- submit form page
- thank you page

Right now, I'm thinking what structure is good for this website.
Should I use module for each page template? for example:

- HomeModule for home page
- ListModule for list page
- DetailModule for detail page
- SubmitFormModule for submit form page

... etc

Or other structure is more better?
Any suggestion is helpful.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion that's kind of overkill. There might be advantages to that as far as lazy loading, but it would make your code a lot more complex.

Angular docs recommend building feature modules, and I've had good luck with that. Basically any separate part of you application you create a module for. For me a lot of times this means how I structure my urls.

```
mysite.com/Admin/Whatever
mysite.com/Account/Whatever
mysite.com/Feature1/Whatever
```

I would make a module for Admin, Account, and Feature1. The different modules would likely share some of the services and models. Each module can then also have its own routing, which is useful if you need auth guards.

You will probably have at least one 'SharedModule' that gets brought in by multiple other modules. Like if you write a component to render lists, and you want that in various spots on your site.

I also usually have a CoreModule, which has the bare minimum I need to run the app. So the NavBar, HomePage, maybe a couple other things I need for the landing page. This is the only module included in the initial bundle, and everything else can be lazy loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely no, you don't need create module for each page. You will need separate module mostly in case if you want to separate some components that widely used by other components, for example. Please read about Angular module system [here](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule)